# How to remove errors (red underlines) in D2007

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a lot of errors in structure panel. The application compiles and run fine with Delphi 2007. But the code have much code that have red underlines. If I press Ctrl + leftclick on it it finds the original declaration. But it is still annoying to have all those errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have `IDE Fix Pack` installed, and still get incorrect error insight red lines regularly.

Some things which help (temporarily)

- Close the project and delete *.local and *.identcache, then re-open the project.
- When Loading a project, wait for the code-folding lines in the gutter to appear (before Delphi 2009, this indicates that the background compiler is finished)

Comment: Thanks, remove those files seems to reduce the glutter a lot.

Answer (score 5):

These are well-known IDE bugs. Have you tried the [IDE Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=15)?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you just want all the red underlines to go away:

*Tools* | *Options* | *Editor Options* | *Code Insight*

Then uncheck **Error insight**

That is for Delphi 2010, but I think it is very similar in Delphi 2007, but I don't currently have it installed.

Comment: No I want them as it informs about errors in the code. Bit a shame it don't always work.

Comment: Unfortunately with D2009 nothing else helped me. So no underlines are better than 50% of the code marked red.